# Transition from one image to another and have it rotate during transtion: CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

http://punkave.com/

The top left Logo: when you hover over it:
How do you code this?
Transition from one image to another and have it rotate.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you haven't read the [how to post manual](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please do so. Stackoverflow is not made to provide ready-made solutions to _how to make something_. You can ask a question if you already tried something and it didn't work. Just keep that it mind!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` on `:hover` for the rotated state. And `transition` for the animation.

```
#logo {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#logo:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```